# adding to a list that is contained in livedata and adding elements to that list

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata

adding to a list that is contained in livedata and adding elements to that list

```
val resourcesLiveData by lazy { MutableLiveData<List<File>>() }
```

I thought this should work as my LiveData is a list of files and I just want to add elements to it. But the value of live data is always an empty list. The `res` is the different file resources I am trying to add

```
resourceLiveData.value?.toMutableList()?.add(res)
```

So I tried it more expicity using this version but the list is still empty

```
val listOfRes = resourceLiveData.value ?: emptyList()
listOfRes.toMutableList().add(res)
resourceLiveData.value = listOfRes.toList()
```

Can anyone see if I am doing something wrong.

Just want to add to the list that is contained in the `value`

Comment: `listOfRes.toMutableList()` will give you a new object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree to @KeyserSoze answer, if you have to use only `List` then you can do below

```
resourceLiveData.value = resourceLiveData.value?.toMutableList()?.apply { add(res) }?: emptyList()
```

Comment: Why do we need the `?: emptyList()`.  It seems to me that the emptyList will only return if the `.apply { add(res) }` is null. Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: No, it will be `null`, `?.` returns `null` if preceding statement is `null`, hence emptyList() is required

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new object by calling `toMutableList()` instead of updating the original.

Change your `LiveData` type to `MutableList`:

```kotlin
val resourcesLiveData by lazy { MutableLiveData<MutableList<File>>() }
```

Then, update the value accordingly:

```kotlin
resourceLiveData.value?.add(res)
```